# Swapping column values of certain rows

Tags: r

With data formatted like so I want to change certain f values to j and j values to f for certain values of C, e.g. when c is 6 7 or 2 I want to swap j for f and vice versa in column A.

```
      A    B           C    
      f    2           2   
      f    2           6 
      j    2           7 
      j    3           3 
      j    3           4 
      f    3           8 
      j    2           2   
      j    2           6 
      f    2           7 
      f    3           3 
      f    3           4 
      j    3           8
```

Comment: While including  example data is a great start, Stack overflow should not a `write my code for me` resource. Please post your (failed) attempts

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had no idea where to start. I'll take longer to attempt before posting in future, was a bit desperate.

Comment: A question on Stackoverflow should *not* be your first port of call in that case.

Comment: It wasn't but I couldn't understand elsewhere- I understand what you mean right now though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
DF <- read.table(textConnection('A    B           C    
  f    2           2   
  f    2           6 
  j    2           7 
  j    3           3 
  j    3           4 
  f    3           8 
  j    2           2   
  j    2           6 
  f    2           7 
  f    3           3 
  f    3           4 
  j    3           8'), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF
##    A B C
## 1  f 2 2
## 2  f 2 6
## 3  j 2 7
## 4  j 3 3
## 5  j 3 4
## 6  f 3 8
## 7  j 2 2
## 8  j 2 6
## 9  f 2 7
## 10 f 3 3
## 11 f 3 4
## 12 j 3 8


DF[DF$C %in% c(6, 7, 2), "A"] <- ifelse(DF[DF$C %in% c(6, 7, 2), "A"] == "f", "j", "f")

DF
##    A B C
## 1  j 2 2
## 2  j 2 6
## 3  f 2 7
## 4  j 3 3
## 5  j 3 4
## 6  f 3 8
## 7  f 2 2
## 8  f 2 6
## 9  j 2 7
## 10 f 3 3
## 11 f 3 4
## 12 j 3 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's cheating:

```
x[x$C %in% c(6,7,2),'A'] <- levels(x$A)[3 - as.numeric(x[x$C %in% c(6,7,2),'A'])]

> x
##    A B C
## 1  j 2 2
## 2  j 2 6
## 3  f 2 7
## 4  j 3 3
## 5  j 3 4
## 6  f 3 8
## 7  f 2 2
## 8  f 2 6
## 9  j 2 7
## 10 f 3 3
## 11 f 3 4
## 12 j 3 8
```